# Polymer sometimes shows white screen in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, polymer-1.0

Sometimes, when I try to load my Polymer 1.0 project in Internet Explorer, I simply get a blank screen. When I inspect the page, all I see is this:

```
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

Where you can't even expand **my-app**. It's like IE isn't recognizing the tag. But, I can refresh a couple times, and then the app will show up properly, and the DOM Explorer shows the correct data.

My project is setup such that the entire app is contained within the **my-app** custom element. I use vulcanize to condense my app to one file, then I use crisper to separate the HTML and the Javascript into 2 separate files.

One thing to note is that I have a second custom element that is used for the login screen. So, in that HTML snippet, it would have

```
<body>
    <my-app-login></my-app-login>
</body>
```

Instead. This seems to always display. So, it's only the **my-app** element having this issue.

Comment: Can you create a jsbin/codepen to demonstrate this?